# Complex distributions - what are the appropriate test functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory

In the theoretical physics literature on conformal field theory, one encounters distributional formulas like
$$
  \frac{1}{\pi}\partial_{\bar z}\frac{1}{z} = \delta(z),
$$
where $\partial_{\bar z}$ is the usual Wirtinger derivative operator defined by
$$
  \partial_{\bar z} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x + i\partial_y).
$$
The usual justification for the formula above is that given an analytic function $\varphi$, and given a disk $D$ containing the origin, one has
\begin{align}
  \int_{D}\varphi(z)\frac{1}{\pi}\partial_{\bar z}\frac{1}{z} \, dx \, dy
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_D \partial_{\bar z}\left(\frac{\varphi(z)}{z}\right)\, dx\, dy
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{\varphi(z)}{z}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}(2\pi i \varphi(0)) \\
&= \varphi(0)
\end{align}
where the second equality follows from Green's Theorem, and the third equality follows from Cauchy's Integral Formula.

It seems that when one performs such computations, one is using some notion of an analytic test function $\varphi$.

Is there a standard theory of distributions on the complex plane which addresses what sorts of test functions $\varphi$ one ought to consider?  If so, what are they? (references more than welcome).

Comment: I must admit I don't get why the proof you wrote should work.  It seems to me that you have to prove it for the usual smooth test functions $\varphi$.  The proof should go along the same lines as the usual proof that $\Del^2 (1/|x|) = - 4\pi \delta(x)$ in 3D.  I have never heard of analytic test functions.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yeah I'm strongly inclined to agree -- I have never heard of analytic test functions either.  Nonetheless, the calculation I wrote down appears in at least the most well-known, standard conformal field theory text, so I'd like to make sense of it somehow.

Comment: Maybe the books are just wrong.  Perhaps one of them thought of this pseudo-proof, and all the others blindly copied.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I wouldn't be surprised in the least, but I'd prefer to defer final judgement until I can be a bit more certain there's a mistake.  Perhaps someone more familiar with CFT will someday have something definitive to say about this.